# Codeigniter - form validation

Tags: forms, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-form-validation

I am validating form in Codeigniter using `form_validation` library and setting rules using an array.

I want validation message on `max_length` like this:

> Username may not be greater than 255 character.

> **%s** may not be greater than %? character.

The problem is I am getting Username using `%s` but I want `255` dynamically in validation message.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|max_length[255]',
    array('required' => 'You must provide a %s.','max_length' => '%s may not be greater than %?'));
```

Comment: [Multiple rules should be separated by pipes, right](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#cascading-rules)?  So `..., 'required|max_length[255]', array(...)` ?

Comment: @Don't Panic yes, you are right multiple rules separated by pipes, by mistakenly typed comma but what is the solution on this question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much reputation points so posting this as an answer.
This can be achieved by using variable

```
$max_len = 100; // Set max length here 
$this->form_validation->set_rules(
        'username', 'Username', "required|max_length[$max_len]",
        array(
                'required'      => 'You have not provided %s.',
                'max_length'     => "%s may not be greater than $max_len"
        )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules(
        'username', 'Username',
        'required|max_length[255]',
        array(
                'required'      => 'You have not provided %s.',
                'max_length'     => '%s may not be greater than 255'
        )
);
```

Comment: what if i change ``max_length[255]`` to ``max_length[100]`` then i have to change array rules manually. This answer is not helping.